# how to resolve skip location change issue in angular

Tags: angular

Hi All i am using angular 7 in my application.

```
this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/user"], {skipLocationChange: true});
```

I am getting below error
[image]

kindly let me know how to resolve it.

routing file

```
export const routes4: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'user',
            component: DashboardWelcomeComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'admin',
            component: DashboardPersonComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
}
```

];

module file

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent, WelcomepageAdminComponent, ProjectLinkspageComponent, AssignedWorkpageComponent,
    CalendarpageComponent, ChartpageComponent, RecentActivitiespageComponent, WelcomepageUserComponent, DashboardPersonComponent, DashboardWelcomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardManagementRoutingModule, ChartAllModule, CalendarModule
  ],
  entryComponents  : [DashboardWelcomeComponent, DashboardPersonComponent],
  providers: [DashboardService]
})
export class DashboardManagementModule { }
```

Comment: Could you please show me your component and app.module?
the error is because data service is not in app.module but dont know what it is without seeing it.

Comment: will update the question with the necessary data in few minutes

Comment: do you have anything called data?

Comment: no, i don't have any data

Comment: So could you please add the component.ts to the question as well

Comment: i have data variable i removed that data from component, now it is working

Comment: there you go! :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app.module "data" missing from your providers array